# local $_ in a Perl subroutine

Tags: perl

Is it correct to write This?

```
sub foobar {
   local $_ = $_[0] if @_;
   s/foo/bar/;
   $_;
}
```

The idea is to take `$_` if no arguments given as `chomp`do. I can then either write

```
foobar($_);
```

or

```
&foobar;
```

Comment: Missing final `/` in the substitution.

Comment: Also, use [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) tells you: `Scalar value @_[0] better written as $_[0]`.

Comment: Many Perl built-in functions use `$_` if an explicit argument is omitted. But relying on this in your own subroutines is not a good idea, in my opinion. It is not *that* hard to type in the argument if it is `$_` : `sfoobar($_)`.

Comment: @TLP This is exactly what kind of information I am looking for. You said isn't a good idea in you opinion. Could you please be less subjective in your answer?

Comment: Using built in variables in different ways is asking for trouble. It can break in unpredictable ways, not least because a maintenance programmer may well not expect you to be  doing it. Is it _really_ so hard to assign and use a named value?

Comment: @Sobrique It is not, I just want to write beautiful code and the definition of beauty is isn't always subjective.

Comment: Clear code is beautiful code. Concise ambiguous code is always filthy.

Comment: @TLP to draw some parallel, many built in functions are also context aware but `wantarray()` is not generally encouraged for user code.

Comment: `Contextual::Return` is also a rather fun way of handling 'smart' subroutines. Of course, when you do, you also rather guarantee that you'll end up with some spooky magic that no one really understand how it works.

Comment: Good on you to challenge these subjective claims, which are mostly rubbish, like  "`wantarray()` is not generally encouraged for user code" -- what a remarkable passively voiced negative ... there isn't any function the use of which is "generally encouraged". And scalar vs. list context *always* affects the result of returning an array or list, and the result is different between them, so `wantarray` (misnamed) is useful to force the desired result. But *objectively*: `&foobar` is wrong -- that passes the caller's args to `foobar`. You want `foobar()`.

Comment: P.S. Most of the answers here, including the one you accepted, are wrong--they don't act like `chomp`, which changes `$_` in the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`local $_ = ... if @_;` will only localize `$_` if the the sub received an argument, meaning it won't protect the caller's `$_` is the sub doesn't receive an argument, and that's not what you want.

The minimal fix is

```
sub sfoobar {
   local $_ = @_ ? shift : $_;
   s/foo/bar/;
   return $_;
}
```

But you might as well use a named variable at this point.

```
sub sfoobar {
   my $s = @_ ? shift : $_;
   $s =~ s/foo/bar/;
   return $s;
}
```

5.10+ introduced the `_` prototype.

```
sub sfoobar(_) {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/foo/bar/;
   return $s;
}
```

5.14+ introduced `s///r`.

```
sub sfoobar(_) {
   return $_[0] =~ s/foo/bar/r;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't correct, no. The trouble is that you can't conditionally `local` something - it's either localised, or it isn't.

Instead of doing that, what I suggest is you localise it, then conditionally copy from `@_`

```
local $_ = $_;
$_ = shift if @_;
```

This way, `$_` is always localised, but only conditionally copied from the first positional argument if one exists.

Comment: or `local $_ = @_ ? shift : $_`

Comment: Re "The trouble is that you can't conditionally local something", Really? Would you care to back that up?

Comment: It's incorrect, but not because the `local` can't be executed conditionally (as weird as that is). It's incorrect because it doesn't always protect the caller's `$_`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass use an outer $_ in a subroutine, you can use the "_" prototype:

```
# dolund.pl
#
use strict;

sub dolund (_)
         { my $p1 = $_[0];
           print "passed parameter is $p1\n";
           }

dolund 12;      # prints 12

my $fred = 21;  # prints 21
dolund $fred;

$_ = 'not 12';
dolund;         # prints "not 12"
```

Obiously, you could use `$p1=~ s/foo/bar/;`  if you like.  I just wanted to demonstrate the implicit passing of `$_`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got to ask - what are you actually trying to accomplish here?

It looks like you want a sub that works like some of the 'builtins' like `chomp`. I would suggest this is bad practice.

- Unexpected things make code maintenance harder. The next guy to maintain your code should never have to think 'wtf?'.
- messing with 'built in' variables - such as reassigning values to `$_` can have very strange consequences.
- if someone sees your subroutine call, they're going to have to go and look what it does anyway. That's almost by definition a bad subroutine.

Question: What's the scope of `$_`?

Answer: "It's complicated" because it's sort of global, but sometimes it's implicitly localized. And sometimes it's not a variable in it's own right, it's an alias that by modifying it you change the original.

This means it's just plain bad news from a code maintainability standpoint.

From: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables

`$_ is by default a global variable. However, as of perl v5.10.0, you can use a lexical version of $_ by declaring it in a file or in a block with my. Moreover, declaring our $_ restores the global $_ in the current scope. Though this seemed like a good idea at the time it was introduced, lexical $_ actually causes more problems than it solves. If you call a function that expects to be passed information via $_ , it may or may not work, depending on how the function is written, there not being any easy way to solve this. Just avoid lexical $_ , unless you are feeling particularly masochistic. For this reason lexical $_ is still experimental and will produce a warning unless warnings have been disabled. As with other experimental features, the behavior of lexical $_ is subject to change without notice, including change into a fatal error.`

Comment: Legacy reasons. Perl was built that way initially, and changing it would break a lot of code.

Comment: muh, `map trim, @a` doesn't sound like a bad practice to me. There are times where it makes sense.